# cellForRowIndexPath without cellidentifier ios

Tags: ios, uitableview

I do not have xib files or storyboards in my project. In this case how do I set the cell identifier? Below is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"test");
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: `UITableViewCell` initializers have `reuseIdentifier:` parameter.

Answer (score 5):

Try to replace you code by this (using ARC) :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

++

Comment: Have to set the tableview delegate and datasource? [myTableview setDelegate:self]; [myTableview setDatasource:self];

Answer (score 0):

If you're just using a UITableViewCell for your table view, you can register that class in viewDidLoad like this:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

Use the same identifier in cellForRowAtIndexPath: that you use here.